# SimpleBatchConfig not picking up my DefaultBatchConfigurer

Tags: spring-batch

I wrote a simple demo to overwrite default jobrepo. Instead of map based I wanted a H2 db to hold persistent metadata.

Therefore I wrote a CustomBatchConfigurer like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("repo-db")
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "repo-db")
    public DataSource getJobRepoDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/src/spring-batch/batch_repo")
                .driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
                .username("sa")
                .password("test")
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

But Spring-Batch is not picking it up:

```
    o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer: No datasource was provided...using a Map based JobRepository
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought I had followed the instructions on spring doc ref.

Thanks and regards,
Jörg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configuration should look more like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(@Qualifier("repo-db") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "repo-db")
    public DataSource jobRepoDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/src/spring-batch/batch_repo")
                .driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
                .username("sa")
                .password("test")
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

If your bean methods are proxied (which is the default), you can also simplify the first bean method to

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(jobRepoDataSource());
}
```

Please also have a second look at the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig

Comment: i followed the same. still the same logs and  spring batch tables are empty after executing job. Any help pls?

Comment: @Satish: Hello Satish,
I hope you already have gotten your answer. Just in case you haven't.
It is as Henning wrote. You do not need to create a custom class by extending BatchConfigurer. 
Just create a ```@Bean``` of BatchConfigurer in your ```@Configuration```class where you are building your Jobs and Steps.
In this Bean you configure the datasource you want to use for persistence.
Regards, Jörg